# How to draw the bitmap icon on title bar when Windows Aero theme is enabled

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, bitmap, mfc, aero

I'm developing a MFC application (**DWM library is not available**). 
I want to draw a bitmap functioning as a button on the title bar. 
However, the bitmap won't present when the Aero theme is enabled in Windows 7 (There are no problem when I disable the Aero theme).
But my application still reactable by clicking on the position of the bitmap.
Does anyone can teach me how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing custom data into the frame area with DWM is described on MSDN, also the hit testing is explained there as well:

[Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195.aspx)

If you search for DWM on the CodeProject site you find some articles that will help you:

[Vista Goodies in C++: Using Glass in Your UI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15770/Vista-Goodies-in-C-Using-Glass-in-Your-UI)

[Draw custom caption with bitmap in Windows 7/Vista Aero theme](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100314/Draw-custom-caption-with-bitmap-in-Windows-Vista)